# Guardar configuraciones y aplicarlas al pulsar tecla

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Quiero modificar los valores de unas variables, guardar diferentes configuraciones y a cada configuración ejecutarla asignando una tecla del teclado del PC. ¿Alguien me podría dar alguna mano o idea para acercarme al resultado que estoy buscando?

```js
import "./styles.css";
import JZZ, { info } from "jzz";


let canal = 1;
let volumen = 127;
let msb = 0;
let lsb = 0;
let prg = 0;


    
// in the environments that support async/await:
JZZ().or('')
     
     .openMidiOut("1").or('')
     .ch(canal)
     .control("7", volumen)
     .control("0", msb)
     .control("32", lsb)
     .program (prg)


     JZZ().openMidiIn("1").or('Cannot open MIDI In port!')
     .and(function() { console.log('MIDI-In: ', this.name()); })
     .connect(function(msg) { console.log(msg.toString()); })
     .wait(10000).close();**
```

Comment: Hola Gabriel, te damos la bienvenida al sitio. El código compartido no parece estar relacionado con el contenido de la pregunta, deberías editar la publicación para añadir el código que lleves así como los problemas/dificultades que estés encontrando. Tal y como está ahora mismo, es muy amplia. Completa el [tour] y lee [ask] donde encontrarás recomendaciones para mejorar tu pregunta y que sea mejor aceptada. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias alvaro, pero como que no? pregunte como podria modificar estas variables con un formulario en Html y cargarlas al presiona una tecla del teclado de pc  `let canal = 1;
let volumen = 127;
let msb = 0;
let lsb = 0;
let prg = 0;`